# Testing async event handlers in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, event-handling

I have an async event handler that processes a message and raises the event `MessageReceived` on the Main Thread once all message processing is complete, i.e.,

```
private async void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Brokered msg)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        var newMsg = msg.GetBody<string>();
        // Long running code to process message...

        Application.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, newMsg);
        }));
    });
 }
```

Now I want to write a unit test (NUnit) that checks that the event is raised, something like

```
[Test]
public void MessageService_ShimRaisesMessageReceived_RaisesMessageReceived()
{
   // Arrange
   var msg = "This is a test message";
   var brokeredMsg = new BrokeredMessage(msg);

   var isFired = false;
   _messageService.MessageReceived += (sender, args) =>  {isFired = true; };

   // Act
   _serviceBusShim.MessageReceived += Raise.Event<EventHandler<BrokeredMessage>>(this, brokeredMsg);

   // Assert
   Assert.That(isFired, Is.True);
}
```

However, the above test will fail since the test attempts to assert before the Task in the EventHandler is run. How do I properly set up the test using NUnit such that the test waits for the Task to run before the Assert takes place.

Comment: I just realised (in hindsight) that I probably don't need to run the message processing is a separate task in the event handler since I'm already executing on a worker thread (i.e. the whole reason why i have to use the dispatcher to invoke the event back on the main thread). However, I still think it is an interesting scenario.

Comment: First, I recommend using `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Application.CurrentDispatcher`; this gives your unit test control over what context raises the event. Second, avoid `async void` - make that handler only call (and `await`) an `async Task` method that contains testable logic.

Comment: what edition of visual studio do you use?